# fill regions outside contour

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, contourf

Is there any simple way to fill regions outside the contour boundary? Take the following example from matplotlib website:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X - 1)**2 - (Y - 1)**2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=(0.1, 1.5))
ax.clabel(CS, inline=True, fontsize=10)
```

This will plot two simple contour of values 0.1 and 1.5.
Now I would like to show regions outside these contours with colors. I tried

```
ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=(0.1, 1.5))
```

but this fills regions between 0.1 and 1.5. What can I do to fill outside region but keep inside transparent/white?
(question edited to remove confusing elements from the previous version)

Comment: What do you call "outside" in this example? Everything is colored.  You could color between two given values, e.g. `ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=[Z.min() - 1, 0.5], colors=['gold'])`.

Comment: @JohanC Hi...I actually wanted what you have shown. Can you please explain why Z.min()-1 is needed in levels. Thanks. (I have edited my question now.)

Comment: In my example code fragment, I used a number that is a bit lower than the minimum. That way it won't leave a region without coloring.  In your example, you could try `ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=(0.1, Z.max()+1))` to color the complete region larger than `0.1`.

Comment: @JohanC Yes, this solved my problem. Thank you very much.